# How to execute a script from a browser that is on a private server?

Tags: linux, permissions, webmin

I am extremely new to Linux / Unix as a whole, so I apologize in advance for any ignorance that may be perceived by this question.

I am trying to execute a script to set up a control panel from the front-end of a server so I can finish setting it up. (For all of the details, I am trying to install the Minecraft control panel "Multicraft" onto my Webmin server).

However, I have ran into the challenge where I know the file's location:

```
/~/multicraft/panel/install.php
```

But I just do not know how to execute this script from the front end, like from a browser. When I navigate to the file's location (https://xxx.xxx.xxx:10000/multicraft/panel/install.php), it just says in big, bold letters: **Error - File not found**.

To elaborate: I have tried accessing this page by using `http://` but for nothing. When I use `http://`, it just loads a blank page with nothing on it.

I have also tried excluding the port (`:10000`) from the link, but when I do that, it says that the page could not be deleted.

I have been following the [tutorial for setting up the Multicraft control panel](http://multicraft.org/site/page?view=install#1.1) as closely as possible for the Linux 64-bit instructions. I have executed all of the commands that they provided as the root user in the ~/ directory.

The commands I have done so far are as follows:

```
# wget http://www.multicraft.org/download?arch=linux64 -O multicraft.tar.gz 
# tar xvzf multicraft.tar.gz
# cd multicraft
# ./setup.sh
```

This is all I have done so far.

What can I do to make this file executable from the likes of a web browser? I am totally confused and out of league with what I'm doing right now. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it's a one time script ask you service provider to run it for you

Comment: @terdon: Yes, the script must be executed from a browser for setup, unfortunately.

I am not sure – if by command line you mean SSH access, I do have that.

Comment: @50-3 I will look into that possibility.

Comment: Why would it need to be executed from a browser? That is _very_ strange. If you have `ssh` access, just do `ssh you@server php ~/multicraft/panel/install.php`.

Comment: @jflory7 by the by this is probably off topic if it's a 3rd party host, Personally having setup a bunch of wordpress sites I just find it easier to get my provider - also more secure :)

Comment: @terdon: The reason is because the script is apparently in a GUI and must be done from the front-end (see here: http://www.multicraft.org/site/page?view=install#1.1).

Comment: And @50-3, that may be my best option. I will keep you posted!

Comment: @terdon: When I loaded it with `http://` the page was just blank, and when I didn't use the port, it failed to load the page.

Comment: OK, let's start again. Please [edit] your question (do not post this as a comment) and explain exactly what you've done. Did you follow the tutorial you linked to? If so, copy/paste the commands your ran and tell us exactly _where_, in which directory, you ran them.

Comment: Please don't tell us 'I followed verbatim', paste the actual commands. For example, there is no such directory as `/~`, there is a `~/` one which is what I guess you mean, I have yet to understand if you ran `setup.sh` as the tutorial said, did you 'follow the instructions'? What were they? Did you run the script as root as the tutorial says? The issue here is that you have done _something_ wrong so simply telling us you followed the instructions is useless.

Comment: @terdon: Sorry for being so unclear – I have edited the question to show the changes.

Comment: It's OK,I know how hard it can be when you don;t really understand what you're doing. Did you run these commands as root? Using `sudo` for example? Did the `setup.sh` script run correctly? It gave you some instructions?

Comment: @terdon: Oh, yes, all of these have been run as the root user. And the `setup.sh` script was installed successfully, with the instructions to install the control panel by going to the page in the question from a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was having was that I had not installed the apache2 web server to my dedicated machine, and the script that Multicraft was wanting me to execute expected the script to be located in `/var/www/html/multicraft/`, which at the time, I was not aware of.

To fix my problem, I first installed apache2 by doing `yum install httpd`, and then I typed `service httpd restart`. After this, my web server was online, and I reexecuted the `setup.sh` file.

Upon doing this, Multicraft placed the front-end files in the web directory for apache2, and I was successfully able to finish the installation.